# Grid Vaadin - data is displaying below grid-scroller

Tags: java, css, grid, vaadin, vaadin7

I have some problem with Grid from Vaadin 7.
I have container with data in Grid. So I was tring to display this on screen, by adding it to vertical layout.

But unfortunately I have the empty box only with 2 scroll bars, and bellow this I have my "grid" with my data.

I try adding a style in chrome to grid-scroller "position:absolute" and then, everything was working fine.

What is the solution for this problem? Have You even have this problem before?

Comment: for sure is't a good exercise for all of us to imagine the problem in your heads, would you please improve on this questions by adding the code, that shows this behaviour? behaviour like this might be influenced by theme and outer-layer containers. also tell us the vaadin version, since it could be a bug long fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add styles, and "position:absolute" to css, and this solved the problem

Comment: Would you mind mark your answer? Your question still appears in unanswered section.